# Cannot find module

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, server, backend

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'C:\My Work\mern-notes-app\server\controllers\notes' imported from C:\My Work\mern-notes-app\server\routes\notes.js

```
import express from "express";
const router =  express.Router()
import {getNotes} from '../controllers/notes';
```

This is what the controllers/notes file include:

```
export const getNotes = (req , res) => {
  res.send("Get all notes")
}
```

```
Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find module 'C:\My Work\mern-notes-app\server\controllers\notes' imported from C:\My Work\mern-notes-app\server\routes\notes.js
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:406:5)
    at finalizeResolution (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:233:11)
    at moduleResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:845:10)
    at defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:1043:11)
    at ModuleLoader.defaultResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:383:12)
    at ModuleLoader.resolve (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:352:25)
    at ModuleLoader.getModuleJob (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:228:38)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:85:39)
    at link (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:84:36) {
  url: 'file:///C:/My%20Work/mern-notes-app/server/controllers/notes',
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
```

Comment: change import to `import {getNotes} from '../controllers/notes.js';` See [ESM Mandatory file extensions](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#mandatory-file-extensions)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.